# Private Key / Public Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I always store my pem files in the .ssh directory and edit the config file with HOST and USER. So I just SSH to a alias (on the config file) and everything works.

Looking at this tutorial:
http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html

I imagine that AWS uses "Public Key Access" method. But I would like to understand why my system doesnt ask a passphrase to unlock the private key?
The pem file is not encrypted?

Comment: the ones aws generates are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your pem file is not encrypted. You can easily find that out by looking at the first 2 lines of the pem file.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
```

(or)

```
 -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If you do not see it encrypted and you want to encrypt your private key:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f <unencrypted-private-key>
```